# Как проверить на равность два вещественных числа в языке Си?

Tags: c, сравнение, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Цель - проверить равенство двух вещественных чисел (`1.2` и `1.2`).

Приведенный код не работает.

```
float a = 1.2;
if (a == 1.2)
{
    printf("Equals");
}
```

Comment: Что значит "код не работает"? Все прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Более подробно:

`1.2` в двоичном виде имеет бесконечное количество знаков после точки: `1.00110011...`.

Бесконечное количество знаков, очевидно, не влезает в память, поэтому это число хранится неточно (округляется).

В `double x = 1.2;` хранится число  `1.0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011`.
В десятичном виде: `1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`.

В `float x = 1.2;` влезает меньше знаков: `1.00110011001100110011010`
В десятичном виде: `1.2000000476837158203125`.

<sup>(Если используется стандарт IEEE 754.)</sup>

Когда вы делаете:

```
float a = 1.2;
if (a == 1.2)
```

Происходит сравнение `float` и `double`. Для этого `float` преобразуется в `double`.

Получается, что вы сравниваете
`1.0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011 == 1.19999999...` и
`1.0011001100110011001101000000000000000000000000000000 == 1.20000004...`, которые конечно же не равны.

Как уже написал @Harry в соседнем ответе, если заменить сравнение на `a == 1.2f`, то проблема пропадет.

Если бы вместо `1.2` стояло какое-то другое число, которое может быть представлено точно в обоих типах (например `1.25`), то ваш код работал бы без изменений.

Answer (score 7):

Вы сравниваете `float` и `double`, а они имеют разные представления.

```
float a = 1.2;
if (a == 1.2f)
{
    printf("Equals");
}
```

Так вы будете сравнивать два `float`. Но учтите, что если 1.2 *вычисляется* - скорее всего равенства не будет, просто из-за того, что только редкие числа представляются в виде типа с плавающей точкой **точно**.

Лучше задавать точность сравнения и проверять равенство типа

```
if (fabs(a-b) < eps) { // равны
```