# Вернуть значение 0.0, вместо -0.0

Tags: c++, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

```cpp
   double y, x;
   double a = -0.5, b = 1.0, h = 0.1;
   x = a;

   for (x; x <= b; x += h) 
       {
           if (x == 0)
           {
               y = sqrt(x + 0.5);
               //cout << "|" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << a << "|" << setw(10) << right << setprecision(5) << y << "|" << endl;
               cout << "|" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << x << "|" << setw(14) << right << "y=sqrt(" << x << "+0.5)=" << setprecision(5) << y << "|" << endl;
           }
           else if (x < 0)
           {
               y = log(x + 2);
               //cout << "|" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << a << "|" << setw(10) << right << setprecision(5) << y << "|" << endl;
               cout << "|" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << x << "|" << setw(15) << right << "y=log(" << x << "+2)=" << setprecision(5) << y << "|" << endl;
           }
           else
           {
               y = (1.0 / x) + (0.2 * x);
               //cout << "|" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << a << "|" << setw(10) << right << setprecision(5) << y << "|" << endl;
               cout << "|" << setw(10) << right << fixed << setprecision(2) << x << "|" << setw(15) << right << "y=(1/" << x << ")+(0.2*" << a << ")=" << setprecision(5) << y << "|" << endl;
           }
       }
```

При вычислении выражения x=-0.1+h, значение переменной x становится равным -0.0 вместо 0.0 и он проходит через второе условие. Как получить заветный 0.0, который будет подходить под третье условие?

Comment: *"значение переменной x становится равным -0.0"* - это вы вляпались в вычисления с плавающей точкой. Вывод идет с `setprecision(2)`, тогда как значение по факту получается `-2.77555756156289135105907917022705078125e-17` и для сравнения придутся делать некоторый допуск

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как проверить на равность два вещественных числа в языке Си?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887818/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%a1%d0%b8)